# Align first widget of Flutter's scrollview initially centeric but all following selected widgets also in the center

Tags: dart, flutter, scrollview

**What I want to achieve**

I want to have the very first widget of a ScrollView initially centered. But if the scrollview gets scrolled, the scrollview should be has the same width as the parent and the centered widget should be the selected one.

**Approach**

My first idea was to use the `initialScrollOffset` property. but this seems to be without any effect.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: _buildCarouselItems(),
      itemExtent: FrettirConstants.cardWidth,
      controller: new ScrollController(
          debugLabel: "Carousel",
          initialScrollOffset: -200,
        keepScrollOffset: true
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Sketch**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may sound like a bad practice to achieve it, but you can add an empty Container with the 3/4 width of other carousel widgets to the first position.

In my dummy code each carousel widget has length 160, and empty Container must have 3/4 of other widgets. This way first carousel widget is fully visible while second one has 3/4 visibility.

```
Container(
  width: 160.0 * 3 / 4,
  color: Colors.transparent,
),
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
    right: 10.0
  ),
  width: 160.0,
  color: Colors.red,
),
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      horizontal: 10.0
  ),
  width: 160.0,
  color: Colors.blue,
),
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. I'll mark this answer as helpful but not at *the answer*. I hope that there will be a more "suitable" way to achieve it.

Comment: Yes this is not a proper answer or solution. I hope this won't be a roadblock to your project.

Comment: No, of course not. You helped to keep "making progress". I can revisted this issue later. Thanks for you help!